# How to notify the user that a notification has arrived using the websocket gorilla

Tags: go, web, websocket, gorilla, channel

How to notify the user that a notification has arrived using the **websocket gorilla**. the socket route looks like **ws://localhost:8080/ws/{id}**. id is the id of the user. I have a notification table in a database. There is a **user_id** field. I would like these users to be notified.

```
func signal(c *websocket.Conn) {
    eventBytes, err := json.Marshal(<-Chann)
    err = c.WriteMessage(1, eventBytes)
    for {
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("err ", err)
            break
        }
        break
    }
}

func (h *notificationHandler) Connect(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := r.URL.Query().Get("id")  
    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("upgrade:", err)
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    for {
        signal(c)
    }
}

func (h *notificationHandler) CreateNotification(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    ...
    go func() {
        Chann <- map[string]string{
            "event": "signal",
        }
    }()
    ...
}
```

Notification Table has id, text, user_id

the client only needs to send a event signal that a new notification has arrived without text

Comment: Create a channel for each connected client and use that channel in signal.  Write code to maintain an association between user ids and and those channels. To send to specific user, send to all channels associated with the user's id.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I was looking for your contacts, but you answered me, I'm glad. Thank you, I'll try to implement